# Can read take more than a single variable?

Tags: shell-script

I want to have someone input two separate numbers for example:

```
 echo "Type two different numbers. For example: 1 3"
```

then take the two separate numbers they type and put them into their own variables. I know the `read` command allows me to take a single value, but is there a way to do two?

Comment: this is in a script also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ read v1 v2
#enter 1 2 

$ echo $v1
1
$ echo $v2
2
```